# time that does not depend in system time

Tags: c++, iphone

I am developing a game in C++ for iPhone. I need to give hourly bonus to the player. I implemented this using time(NULL) method to check for next. But that can cheated easily by changing the device time. So what alternative I have to prevent this?

I of my friend told me to sync that to my server. But that is not an option as no server communication is there at present. Please help...

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Does iOS have POSIX clock_gettime()? If you pass CLOCK_MONOTONIC to that you get a timer should never go backwards.

Comment: I'm planning to build it cross platform. So I want to minimise the iOS specific function calls

Comment: It's a POSIX function. Only Windows won't have it.

Comment: Sorry. I'll check that. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 2):

C++11 defines the [`std::steady_clock`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/steady_clock) for this purpose. The Boost library provides it as well: [`boost::chrono::steady_clock`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/chrono/reference.html#chrono.reference.cpp0x.system_clocks_hpp.steady_clock).

Example code in C++11:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
   auto start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
   /* Do something as time passes... */
   auto end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();

   auto elapsed = end - start;
   std::cout << "Time passed: " << elapsed.count() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: how would he implement the steady_clock? interested

Comment: @Need4Sleep You mean, how it's used? I have now added an example for that.

Comment: Is this in the MSVC C++ standard library yet? I'd like to see how they implement it. Getting the time on Windows has always been such a pain for me.

Comment: @dupersuper I don't know (I never use MSVC). But does this answer it, I wonder: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874790.aspx

Comment: @jogojapan It does. It doesn't show their code though. I suppose it's compiled away into their libc++ and we can't see it.

Comment: @jogojapan Can I assign std::chrono::steady_clock::now() into a long variable?

Comment: No, not safely at least. It returns a [`std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point). What would you like to do with the `long`? If the goal is to get seconds or minutes or anything like that, best take the interval between two time points (which is a `chrono::duration`), and then apply the correct conversion functions, e.g. see the example code here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/duration

Comment: @jogojapan I want to store the current time and compare that in future

Comment: Why not store it as `std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::steady_clock>` then? You can put it in vectors, maps and the like as well. And of course you can use a typedef if the name is too long.

Comment: @jogojapan I want to save that in device. Even if the user quits the game and launches it again after days it has to be there

Comment: Oh, you need the time to be steady even after the process has been shut down, and is restarted? `std::chrono::steady_clock` won't continue ticking after the process is shut down. But couldn't you measure the time spent in the game _while the process is running_? So when the game is shut down, you log the time difference between start up time and shut down time. The next time the user plays again, you do the same. This way you know how much time the user spent in the game. (You won't know how much time was spent _outside_ the game, but does that matter?)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19277/discussion-between-aaron-and-jogojapan)